# Transition effect on a :after element with JQuery toggleclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using toggleClass to add a class `.expend` to a div `#menu` which expend the height of the menu from 100 to 200px, with a smooth transition (in and out).
I also have an element `#menu:after` for design purposes.

My problem is that when the class `.expend` is toggled and my :after element appears, ther is no fade in (nor fade out) animation.

I'm looking for a clean way to add the same transition animation effect that my menu has to my pseudo-element after has. How can I do that ?

```js
 $('#link').click( function() {
  $("#menu").toggleClass("expend");
  $('.input-area').fadeToggle(300);
 } );
```

```css
#menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}

#menu.expend {
  height: 200px !important;
}

#menu.expend:after {
  content: 'how to get a 0.3 transition effect here (fade in and fade out) ?';
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" href="#">click me</a>
<div id="menu">
  <div class="input-area">
    <input type="text" name="test" id="test" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set a CSS transition on the pseudo for `#menu:after` & `#menu.expend:after`  since generated content is not part of the DOM, javascript cannot reach it :)

```js
$('#link').click( function() {
  $("#menu").toggleClass("expend");
  $('.input-area').fadeToggle(300);
 } );
```

```css
#menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: 0.25s ease-out;
}

#menu.expend {
  height: 200px !important;
}
/* set values of your own , idem for transition timing :) */
#menu:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 0px solid red;
  transition:height 0.3s, top 0.3s, border 0.25s ;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#menu.expend:after {
  content: 'how to get a 0.3 transition effect here (fade in and fade out) ?';
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" href="#">click me</a>
<div id="menu">
  <div class="input-area">
    <input type="text" name="test" id="test" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, allright I understand why I couldn't get it done now. However what I was looking for was a Fade in/out more like the input one (slowly appearing/disapearing). Since JS can't reach it, is there a way to do it with CSS ? edit: maybe by playing with visibility/opacity ? I'm going to try everything I can !

Comment: @apatik opacity will take transition, visibility will not ( 0->1 can be hundreds of steps . visible/hidden just switch from one to the other) ;)